# Emirates - Check in Baggage Dimensions from India to USA

Tags: usa, india, check-in, emirates

My journey is from Ahmedabad to Dubai(Emirates Economy), Dubai to Boston(Emirates Economy) and Boston to Cleveland(JetBlue Economy). On their website emirates mentions that checked in baggage dimensions should not exceed total of 150 cm - if we go by this calculation I can not even check in my large size trolly bag of (77 x 47 x 35 cm). This just seems a bit too much. Can someone who has previously travelled Emirates help me out here? Do they really check this dimensions? I am planning to check in 2 bags - (77 x 47 x 35 cm), will it be okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Emirates website:](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/baggage/checked-baggage.aspx)

> The total dimensions (length + width + height) of each piece must not
>   exceed 150 cm (59 inches).

Your maximum dimensions exceed by 9 cms. Emirates is more likely to just ignore this.